# IP телефония, пропадает интернет

Tags: ip, voip, elastix

[image: Всем привет, помогите разобраться.]

Есть сервер Elastix с билайн транком, и телефоны Yealink SIP-T21P E2, при звонках внутр. номера все хорошо работает, но стоит позвонить по внешке, так сразу съедает весь интернета, интернет не будет работать пока не положишь трубку. Установил приложение "CSipSimple" на свой андроид телефон, и с него все прекрасно работает.

Comment: А интернет случайно не через 3G?